# How can I make the node server with only accept some port?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have LAMP server now I want another server connect to my mysql with another ip address how can I do that

I don't know the keyword to search I will explain with the picture

```
[client] ---> [cloudflare] ---> [my LAMP]
user view with port 80              ^
                                    |
                                    |
                                port 3306
            [my another server so I can hide my real ip address of my LAMP]
                                    ^
                                    |
                                    |
                                port 3306
              [another server want to connect only mysql]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the use case behind not wanting your database server to know the IP of your webserver? Any standard load balancer should fit there.

Comment: I've found this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-mysql-load-balancing--3 I think it should solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql proxy ( https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/ )  is a simple program that sits between your client and MySQL server(s) that can monitor, analyze or transform their communication.